# Changing Color of a Turtle Drawing Later in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I was trying to recreate a check box for a project I was working on in Python using the turtle module. To do this, I imagined that the color of the turtle at the time of making the checkbox would be nothing and once the user clicked on the box, it would change color. I used a variable but it does not seem to work.

```
color = ((0,255,0))
def Options():
    global color
    opts = turtle.Screen()
    opts.setup(800,800)
    opts.reset()
    opts.title('Options')
    turtle.onscreenclick(None)
    boxes = turtle.Turtle()
    boxes.ht()
    boxes.up()
    boxes.sety(300)
    boxes.write('Character Control', align = 'center', font = ('Verdana', 30, 'normal'))
    boxes.goto(-200,250)
    boxes.pd()
    boxes.begin_fill()
    for i in range(4):
        boxes.fd(50)
        boxes.rt(90)
    boxes.color(color)
    boxes.end_fill()
    boxes.up()
    boxes.goto(0,207)
    boxes.write('Attracted to food.', align = 'center', font = ('Verdana', 20, 'normal'))
    boxes.goto(-200,180)
    boxes.pd()
    for i in range(4):
        boxes.fd(50)
        boxes.rt(90)
    boxes.up()
    boxes.goto(14, 140)
    boxes.write('Attracted to poison.', align = 'center', font = ('Verdana', 20, 'normal'))
    turtle.listen()
    turtle.onscreenclick(checked)
def checked(x,y):
    global color
    if x in range(-200, -150) and y in range(200,250):
        color = (255, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The immediate issue is this function:

```
def checked(x,y):
    global color
    if x in range(-200, -150) and y in range(200,250):
        color = (255, 0, 0)
```

The `x` and `y` parameters are floats so will never be found in a range of integers.  Instead try:

```
def checked(x, y):
    global color

    if -200 < x < -150 and 200 < y < 250:
        color = (255, 0, 0)
```

> I imagined that the color of the turtle at the time of making the
>   checkbox would be nothing and once the user clicked on the box, it
>   would change color.

When you successfully click on a box and reset the `color` variable, it has no effect on the turtle nor the boxes.  It simply sets a variable.  You lack sufficient code to make the boxes do something.

However, this is the wrong way to go about the problem.  The simpler approach is to make each checkbox a turtle, and set their individual `onclick()` event handlers rather than the screen's global one.  Here's an example building on your existing code:

```
import turtle

screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.colormode(255)

color = (0, 255, 0)

STAMP_SIZE = 20

box1 = box2 = None

def Options():
    global box1, box2

    opts = turtle.Screen()
    opts.setup(800, 800)
    opts.reset()
    opts.title('Options')

    boxes = turtle.Turtle(visible=False)
    boxes.up()
    boxes.sety(300)
    boxes.write('Character Control', align='center', font=('Verdana', 30, 'normal'))
    boxes.up()

    box1 = turtle.Turtle('square', visible=False)
    box1.shapesize(50 / STAMP_SIZE)
    box1.penup()
    box1.goto(-200, 225)
    box1.color('black', color)
    box1.onclick(checked1)
    box1.showturtle()

    boxes.goto(0, 207)
    boxes.write('Attracted to food.', align='center', font=('Verdana', 20, 'normal'))

    box2 = turtle.Turtle('square', visible=False)
    box2.shapesize(50 / STAMP_SIZE)
    box2.penup()
    box2.goto(-200, 155)
    box2.color('black', 'white')
    box2.onclick(checked2)
    box2.showturtle()

    boxes.goto(14, 140)
    boxes.write('Attracted to poison.', align='center', font=('Verdana', 20, 'normal'))

def checked1(x, y):
    box2.fillcolor('white')
    box1.fillcolor(color)

def checked2(x, y):
    box1.fillcolor('white')
    box2.fillcolor(color)


Options()

turtle.mainloop()
```

Now clicking on one of the checkboxes will turn it green and the other white.  This should give you the underpinnings to make the checkboxes do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I was wondering if it was possible to have both of the check boxes could be selected. Not that you need to spend time working on it. @cdlane

Comment: @rbhog, yes, you can have them be independent checkboxes, just change the logic in the `checked1()` and `checked2()` event handers.  For example just have `checked1()` look at the fill color of `box1` and switch to the other state.

Comment: That is what I thought I would need to do.